# Postig form with file upload and showing wait time

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a form which allows users to upload files. Its a multi-step form (using simple hide/show on the various divs within the form) so the only time the form gets submitted is at the end when the user clicks Submit.

When the user clicks submit the form posts to a ColdFusion page that handles everything can also return a result of success in JSON format. I understand that you cannot use AJAX to submit a form with attachments (unless using a plugin of some kind maybe).

Could anyone let me know how to have a form that will post data to another page and show a progress bar while its being processed. Once the 'success' result is returned by JSON from the other page, it can then redirect to a success page or whatever. I've tried using JQuery's AJAX but it won't send the file data obviously so the only way has been to post the form direct to the ColdFusion page without JQuery involved. This works but if the user submit huge files he won't know why the page is hanging for so long and how much longer he has to wait.

Is this possible? I'm using ColdFusion 10 and JQuery 1.9.1 (but can use 2.0 if need be).

Here is what I have so far:

```
     $("#my-form").on('click', 'input[type="submit"]', function (e) {
            if (!$("#my-form").valid()) { //if form is invalid, show errors and don't submit
              e.preventDefault();
                return;
            } 
else {
    // Form validated so is posted to server. 
    // How to wait for the CF page to return a successful JSON result? 
    // A spinner probably is enough to show the page is doing something.

    }
        });
```

Comment: I can suggest few pointers like the [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or use FormData API in modern browsers see http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: Thanks Arun... I added some code to my question so that you may be able to understand my thinking.

Comment: What browsers are you required to support? It's not really practical in older browsers, but in newer browsers it is possible. Unfortunately, CF isn't going to help you much here: your code is only run when the file has been fully transmitted, so really it's the client which is going to have to monitor the progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use :[Jquery blueimp file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). highly recommended

The plugin has great support, cross broswer, and all thats needed for the user interface.

Comment: thanks dagan, i've gone with Jquery Form plugin and it seems to work nicely